# what's the difference between "Remarks" and "Note"?

Tags: word-usage, business-language, differences

When I make a table, there is a column we left for the things we forget to write down on it. What would we call this item? Remarks or Note?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use *Remarks* if the material was of interest to the document reader.  I would use *Notes* if the material was a reminder to the author that re-work might be required.

Comment: Hi, Nice answer. But actually, I mean that what's the best choice for the situation if I just want to remind the worker please do not forget to write down the important things which was not include in the table.

Comment: In that case I would use *Notes.*

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: @IvandroJao  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I would use

**Remarks** - for short words

**Note** - for long words, bullet points or even a long paragraph